# Angular 5: Testing a service using window

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5

I have a service that has a method that checks the available browser quota storage and returns an Observable:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    hasAvailableStorage(): Observable<boolean> {
        const nav: any = navigator;

        return Observable.create(observer => {
            nav.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(
                (usedBytes, grantedBytes) => {
                    observer.next(usedBytes <= grantedBytes * 0.8);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

I want to unit test this service, but I don't know how to get access to the window in the test or to mock the window/webkitTemporaryStorage.

I tried the following, but then it gives an error that the window.webkitTemporaryStorage is read only and cannot be assigned to:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { StorageService } from "./storage.service";

@Injectable()
class MockWebkitTemporaryStorage {
    queryUsageAndQuota(cb) {
        return cb(10, 15);
    }
}

describe("storage.service", () => {
    let service: StorageService;

    const nav: any = window.navigator;
    nav.webkitTemporaryStorage = MockWebkitTemporaryStorage;

    beforeAll(() => {
        service = new StorageService();
    });

    it("should return the result of hasAvailableStorage()", () => {
        const result = service.hasAvailableStorage();
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I am expecting that I have to use some kind of spy on the window navigator/queryUsageAndQuota eventually, but I cannot see how I should set up or complete the test in order to do this. It would be great if someone could help me and provide some example in a detail! :)

**EDIT** changed test (after comments):

```
describe("storage.service", () => {
    let service: StorageService;

    beforeAll(() => service = new StorageService());

    it("should return the result of hasAvailableStorage()", () => {
        const spy = spyOn(navigator["webkitTemporaryStorage"], "queryUsageAndQuota").and.callFake(MockWebkitTemporaryStorage);
        const result = service.hasAvailableStorage();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

After this, the test fails with the error: 'Expected spy queryUsageAndQuota to have been called.'

Comment: Quick question : are those navigator methods native, or are you creating them ?

Comment: Those are native methods which are just called in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your answer to my comment, here is my answer : **you are not testing it right**.

Since those methods are native methods (that I assume you don't override), you should not test if they work. They're made to work. What you should test is if **they're called**.

Your test should look like this :

```
describe("storage.service", () => {
    let service: StorageService;

    beforeAll(() => service = new StorageService());

    it("should return the result of hasAvailableStorage()", () => {
        const spy = spyOn(navigator["webkitTemporaryStorage"], "queryUsageAndQuota").and.callFake(MockWebkitTemporaryStorage);
        service.hasAvailableStorage().subscribe(() => {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Now you are testing if the navigator calls the right function, you mock this function, return something, and you expect the function to have been called.

This should do the trick.

Comment: With your code is gives: "(TS) Property 'webkitTemporaryStorage' does not exist on type Navigator", so I made it "(navigator as any).webkit....." in the spyOn and the expect calls. Then the output error is: Expected spy queryUsageAndQuota to have been called, and the test is failing.

Comment: I just checked myself : those methods don't exist in the navigator object (well they do but are deprecated). Maybe you should use something else ? Otherwise if you want to use it, maybe you should recreate it (with a dummy stub) just to see if they're called. You know how to do that ?

Comment: No I don't know for sure how to do that. Is that kind of the same like mocking it?

Comment: almost :) in one line : `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage = function() { return {queryUsageAndQuota: (usedBytes, grantedBytes) => {}}; }
` this will create dummy functions and (normally) get rid of your error

Comment: Then I get the same error as I started with: " TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'webkitTemporaryStorage' of object '[object Navigator]' ". I change your oneliner to two lines: const nav: any = navigator;
    nav.webkitTemporaryStorage = () => ({ queryUsageAndQuota: (usedBytes, grantedBytes) => {} });, and added it just before the beforeAll in the test.

Comment: ... I'm dumb. Try the answer I gave (not the comments), and replace `spyOn(navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage` with `spyOn(navigator['webkitTemporaryStorage']`

Comment: I edited my post with your comments and it fails with same error as before.

Comment: even with `navigator['webkitTemporaryStorage']` ? Because your error is actually a Typescript definition not up to date

Comment: Yes, see my original post and the edited test at the end. I used it exactly as stated there.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit. Could you delete your nav variable and use the syntax I gave you in your service ?

Comment: Thanks, I edited your answer with the working solution!

Comment: Great, you even do my work :D Good luck with your tests !