# Angular 5: Testing a service with native method and .then

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5

About 3 months ago, I asked this question ([earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165201/angular-5-testing-a-service-using-window/48165648?noredirect=1#comment83313298_48165648)) about testing a service that has a method that checks the available browser quota storage and returns an Observable. Since the functionality of this service only works with Google Chrome, I changed it to be applicable with Firefox as well. The service now looks as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as bowser from "bowser";

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    hasAvailableStorage(): Observable<boolean> {
        if (!bowser.chrome && !bowser.firefox) {
            return Observable.create(obs => obs.next(true));
        }
        if (bowser.chrome || bowser.firefox) {
            return Observable.create(observer => {
                (navigator as any).storage.estimate().then(
                    estimate => {
                        observer.next(estimate.usage <= estimate.quota * 0.8);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I want to unit test this service, so I created a spec-file containing the following:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { StorageService } from "./storage.service";

@Injectable()
class MockStorage {
    estimate() {
        return { usage: 10, quota: 15 };
    }
}

describe("storage.service", () => {
    let service: StorageService;

    beforeAll(() => service = new StorageService());

    it("should return the result of hasAvailableStorage()", () => {
        const spy = spyOn(navigator["storage"], "estimate").and.callFake(MockStorage);
        service.hasAvailableStorage().subscribe(() => {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

When running this test I get the following TypeError:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I do not really understand:

1. why estimate() is undefined
2. how to fix the test

Besides this, I was wondering if there is anything like this that works for IE as well? (no clear explanation I have found on The Internet...)

It would be great if someone could help me and provide some example in a detail! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your question for IE, but for your issue, that's because you return an object instead of promise. That's easily seeable : you don't have a `then` returned by your mock.

From that, two solutions : you either mock a promise, or you mock the return. I'll go for the second one.

```
class MockStorage {
  estimate() {
    return Promise.resolve({ usage: 10, quota: 15 });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I understand it, but your suggested solution displays the same error.

Comment: Stop calling fake, start calling through, and inject your mock directly into your test

Comment: Or spy on the staorage directly : `spyOn(navigator, "storage").and.returnValue(MockStorage)`

Comment: It even works with callThrough without injecting a mock: `const spy = spyOn(navigator["storage"], "estimate").and.callThrough();` Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Directly spying on the storage is not possible in the way you are showing, since it gives the error: `(TS) Argument of type "storage" is not assignable to parameter of type '"authentication" | "cookieEnabled" | "gam...'`, and with the message that there is a parameter type mismatch.

Comment: Try typing your spy like this `spyOn<any>(naviagator, 'storage')`

Comment: This gives antoher error: `{"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nExpected spy storage to have been called.",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nExpected spy storage to have been called."}`. Since the solution with callThrough() works for me, I will use that. Thanks!

Comment: This error means that your spy hasn't been called. You probably changed something else, but I can't tell what with your code. And if it works, then great, use this solution ! As a piece of advice, you have **a lot** of ways of creating spies in Jasmine, so don't bother on how you do it, but rather on if it works !